# What am I missing from this csv reader for TensorFlow?

Tags: tensorflow

It is mostly a copy paste from the tutorial, on the website. I am getting an error:

> Invalid argument: ConcatOp : Expected concatenating dimensions in the
>   range [0, 0), but got 0    [[Node: concat = Concat[N=4, T=DT_INT32,
>   _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](concat/concat_dim, DecodeCSV, DecodeCSV:1, DecodeCSV:2, DecodeCSV:3)]]

the contents of my csv file is:

> 3,4,1,8,4

```
 import tensorflow as tf


filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(["test2.csv"])

reader = tf.TextLineReader()
key, value = reader.read(filename_queue)

# Default values, in case of empty columns. Also specifies the type of the
# decoded result.
record_defaults = [[1], [1], [1], [1], [1]]
col1, col2, col3, col4, col5 = tf.decode_csv(
    value, record_defaults=record_defaults)
# print tf.shape(col1)

features = tf.concat(0, [col1, col2, col3, col4])
with tf.Session() as sess:
  # Start populating the filename queue.
  coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
  threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)

  for i in range(1200):
    # Retrieve a single instance:
    example, label = sess.run([features, col5])

  coord.request_stop()
  coord.join(threads)
```

Comment: It is unfortunate that the sample code (http://tensorflow.org/how_tos/reading_data/index.md) contains this error

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The issue arises due to the shape of the tensors in your program. ***TL;DR*** Instead of `tf.concat()` you should use `tf.pack()`, which will transform the four scalar `col` tensors into a 1-D tensor of length 4.

Before we start, note that you can use the `get_shape()` method on any `Tensor` object to get static shape information about that tensor. For example, the commented-out line in your code could be:

```
print col1.get_shape()
# ==> 'TensorShape([])' - i.e. `col1` is a scalar.
```

The `value` tensor returned by `reader.read()` is a scalar string. `tf.decode_csv(value, record_defaults=[...])` produces, for each element of `record_defaults`, a tensor of the same shape as `value`, i.e. a scalar in this case. A scalar is a 0-dimensional tensor with a single element. [`tf.concat(i, xs)`](http://tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/array_ops.md#concat) is not defined on scalars: it concatenates a list of N-dimensional tensors (`xs`) into a new N-dimensional tensor, along dimension `i`, where `0 <= i < N`, and there is no valid `i` if `N = 0`.

The [`tf.pack(xs)`](http://tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/array_ops.md#pack) operator is designed to solve this problem simply. It takes a list of `k` N-dimensional tensors (with the same shape) and packs them into an N+1-dimensional tensor with size `k` in the 0th dimension. If you replace the `tf.concat()` with `tf.pack()`, your program will work:

```
# features = tf.concat(0, [col1, col2, col3, col4])
features = tf.pack([col1, col2, col3, col4])

with tf.Session() as sess:
  # Start populating the filename queue.
  # ...
```

Comment: The csv section needs clarification and expanding that is for sure.  It took me about 15 minutes to learn enough to encode the neural network I designed for my particular problem using the tensorflow framework.  It has taken a half day so far to figure out how to read some very simple csv data.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! Please raise a GitHub issue if there are specific things that you'd like us to clarify: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues

Answer (score 1):

I am also stuck with this [tutorial](http://tensorflow.org/how_tos/reading_data/index.md). I was able to exchange one problem for another, when I changed your `with tf.Session()` for:

```
sess = tf.Session()
coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)

for i in range(2):
    #print i
    example, label = sess.run([features, col5])

coord.request_stop()
coord.join(threads)

sess.close()
```

The error disappeared, TF started to run, but it looks like it is stuck. If you uncomment `# print` you will see that only one iteration runs. Most probably this is not really helpful (because I trade an error for infinite execution).